# MS Access Sql query not part of aggregate function. Using with Count function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to execute this query on Access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Phys.FName, 
Phys.LName, COUNT(*) AS NumberPatients
FROM Phys, Summary 
WHERE (((Summary.Phys_ID)=[Enter Physician Id]))
AND Phys.Phys_ID = Summary.Phys_ID;
```

but I get this error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression "FName" as part of an aggregate function. (Error 3122)

The query works fine with just the count or just the distinct FName/LName. It is only a problem when I combine them.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY Phys.FName, Phys.LName

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by`, not `select distinct`, and an explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Phys.FName, Phys.LName, COUNT(*) AS NumberPatients
FROM Phys INNER JOIN
     Summary 
     ON hys.Phys_ID = Summary.Phys_ID
WHERE Summary.Phys_ID = [Enter Physician Id]
GROUP BY Phys.FName, Phys.LName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT Phys.FName, 
Phys.LName, COUNT(*) AS NumberPatients
FROM Phys, Summary 
WHERE (((Summary.Phys_ID)=[Enter Physician Id]))
AND Phys.Phys_ID = Summary.Phys_ID
Group by Phys.FName, Phys.LName
```

When you are using an aggregate function with other columns, you have to group by those columns to get result. For more info read [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0)

Comment: you are welcome :) Accept either of the answers. Regards